# Why does an object go out of scope when passed as a pointer, but not when it is returned

Tags: c++, scope, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Making a very simple linked list I found myself confused about what is probably a very simple scoping concept. The first works as expected. It would seem that in the second makeNode function the node "n" is going out of scope at termination.  I'm confused why this is happening.

I'm pretty sure the allocated memory is still there, and both methods have a pointer to that memory.  So why is one not working?

the Program has two make node functions

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node* next;
    Node() : next(NULL){}
};

Node* makeNode1(int value)
{
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->value = value;
    return n;
}

void makeNode2(int value, Node* mountPt)
{
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->value = value;
    mountPt = n;
}

void destroyNode(Node* mountPt)
{
    if(mountPt->next != NULL)
    {
        destroyNode(mountPt->next);
        delete mountPt;
    }
}

int main() {
    Node* origin = NULL;

    // This works
    origin = makeNode1(4);

    // causes a runtime error when dereferenced
    makeNode2(4, origin);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Open the chapter in your C++ book that explains the difference between passing function parameters by value, versus passing them by reference, and read it. You're passing it by value, and `makeNode2`  leaks memory. The pointer passed to is is not initialized, and it remains uninitialized in the caller, because it was passed by value. That's how C++ works.

Comment: There is a leak in `makeNode2`, you should add the line `if(mountPt) delete mountPt;` to make sure to delete previous allocation first, and then its okay to assign `n`.

Comment: Vuwox is correct.

Comment: @Amadeus Yes, I understand that the above compile, but without the delete, this function create a memory leak. And by adding it, compiler will not gives `parameter 'mountPt' set but not used` will using full warnings level, and also the runtime error won't append either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `makeNode2` the pointer parameter `mountPt` is passed-by-value itself, then any modification on the pointer itself inside the function like `mountPt = n;` has nothing to do with the original argument `origin`.

You can change it to pass-by-reference, i.e.

```
void makeNode2(int value, Node*& mountPt)
```

Comment: Note that doing this causes a memory leak; the original `origin` pointer allocated in `makeNode1` gets replaced by the new one allocated in `makeNode2` without being `delete`-ed.

Comment: I'm aware.  Obviously only one function is needed.  I was simply showing both configurations.

Answer (score 1):

In the first instance, you are creating a new section of memory with a pointer to that section of memory (which is just an address) and then returning that address. The second example passes in a pointer to an address in memory and then reassigns that address (i.e. changes that value) in the scope of the function. However, the value of that pointer (the address it refers to) reverts back to its previous call once the function exits as the pointer has a value on the stack already. The difference is in the first call you change the value stored in the address that is ultimately passed out of the function, while in the second you change the address that the pointer is pointing to, but that pointer goes back to pointing to the old address once you change scope back to the main body.

Comment: Passing a pointer by value will still allow you to permanently change the value stored at an address, but does not allow you to change what the pointer points to.

Comment: "reverts back" is a poor way to describe it. The source never changes at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function for the following:

```
void makeNode2(int value, Node* mountPt)
{
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->value = value;
    if(mountPt) delete mountPt;
    mountPt = n;
}
```

where if mountPt was already allocated, it will be freed, and then `origin` could point on the allocation `n`

Comment: I agree that this would be better memory management, but won't this have the same  scope issue?

Comment: @mreff555 Yes it would.

Comment: It actually doesn’t. But if a reference operator is appended to the Node* parameter, as mentioned above, it works

Answer (score 0):

X-Y solution: eliminate the need for a `makeNode` function by expanding the Node constructor

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node* next;
    Node(int val = 0) :value(val), next(NULL){}
};
```

Usage

```
Node * origin = new Node(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

While all above - including the accepted answer - are relevant, none directly point to the actual logical flaw. Instead of `mountPt = n;`, you need `mountPt->next = n;`.